# TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str - iterating list

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I would like to do something like this:

```
def create(stuff):
    someString = ''
    for i in stuff:
        someString += stuff[i]
        print(someString)

create(['Foo', 'Bar'])  
# -> FooBar
```

I tried to change it to string like this:

```
someString += str(stuff[i])
```

but still get error.

Comment: `i` is the string itself, it's not an index: `someString += i`

Comment: A simple `print(i)` in the loop would have revealed this to you instantly.

Comment: Also `''.join(stuff)` is the preferred way to join an iterable.

Answer (score 3):

When you use a `for in` loop, `i` will be equal to the object itself, not the index. In Python, if you wanted to iterate by index, you could for example use `range`:

```
someString = ''
for i in range(len(stuff)):
    someString += stuff[i]
    print(someString)
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the way you are accessing the elements in `stuff`. The following code does it correctly and the explanation follows:

```
def create(stuff):
    someString = ''
    for element in stuff:
        someString += element

    print(someString)
```

When you use Python's [`for` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements), unlike C/C++/Java etc. `for` loops, you don't work with indexes. So, when iterating over a list (or any other [iterable](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterable)) like `for i in ['a', 'b', 'c']`, the value of `i` will be the actual value in the iterable. For example, in the first iteration, `i` will be `'a'` and not `0` (as in the 0th index)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the `stuff[i]`. `i` is not an integer, it is a string.

```
>>> x = ['hi', 'bye']
>>> for k in x:
...        print k
... 
hi
bye
>>>
```

Instead, change it to the following:

```
def create(stuff):
    someString = ''
    for i in range(len(stuff)):
        someString += stuff[i]
        print(someString)
```

Or:

```
def create(stuff):
    someString = ''
    for i in stuff:
        someString += i
        print(someString)
```

The first example uses indices, and the second uses a plain `for` loop.