# Python - For loop 'TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple'

Tags: python, list, tuples

I'm trying to use a for loop to iterate through the first element of a list of tuples.

```
for i in link_list:
    print 'http://www.newyorksocialdiary.com%s' % link_list[i][0]
```

However, I get this error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-72-8c0e1be937a4> in <module>()
      1 for i in link_list:
----> 2     print 'http://www.newyorksocialdiary.com%s' % link_list[i][0]

TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple
```

How can I iterate through the list of tuples and print only the first element, such as:

```
'http://www.newyorksocialdiary.com/party-pictures/2014/the-thanksgiving-day-parade-from-the-ground-up'
'http://www.newyorksocialdiary.com/party-pictures/2014/gala-guests'
```

If it helps, this is what link_list looks like:

```
[('/party-pictures/2014/the-thanksgiving-day-parade-from-the-ground-up',
  datetime.datetime(2014, 12, 1, 0, 0)),
 ('/party-pictures/2014/gala-guests', datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 24, 0, 0)),
 ('/party-pictures/2014/equal-justice', datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 20, 0, 0)),
 ('/party-pictures/2014/celebrating-the-treasures',
  datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 18, 0, 0)),
 ('/party-pictures/2014/associates-and-friends',
  datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 17, 0, 0))]
```

Comment: Use `% i[0]` because `for` loops by default iterate over the container elements, not the indices.

Comment: It looks like your link list contains tuples... Something like `link_list = [(1, "foo"), (2, "bar")...]` Also, keep in mind that when you do `for i in list()`, you get (in `i`) **items** in the list, not indexes (maybe you wanted to do something like `for i in range(len(link_list))`?

Comment: I ran into some lag, so some of the post wasn't posted. finishing the writing of it now.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str - iterating list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23326716/typeerror-list-indices-must-be-integers-not-str-iterating-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've misunderstood the way for loops work in Python. `i` is not an index, it's the element itself. You should use `% i[0]`.

Comment: wow, im completely overlooked it. thank you! selected for answer because it was answered first.

Comment: there's a 3 minute delay. i just logged back in. thanks for the kind reminder.

Answer (score 0):

You can do either:

```
for i in link_list:
    print 'http://www.newyorksocialdiary.com%s' % i[0]
```

or if you need the actual index for some other reason:

```
for i in range(len(link_list)):
    print 'http://www.newyorksocialdiary.com%s' % link_list[i][0]
```

When you do `for i in link_list`, `i` is an element of the list, not the index.