# How to solve type error: "list indices must be integers or slices, not str" in a for loop

Tags: python, list, for-loop

While trying to simply remove an item from a list, I stumbled upon the following problem: "list indices must be integers or slices, not str".

Although I generally get the meaning of the problem, I still do not see what I did wrong. Here's the code:

```py
list1 = ["1", "2", "4", "5", "3"]

for i in list1:
    if list1[i] in ["3"]:
        list1.pop(i)
        break
print(list1)
```

Here's the full error:

```
TypeError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-56-4c691675d0cb> in <module>
      4 for i in list1:
----> 5     if list1[i] in ["3"]:
      6         list1.pop(i) 

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Comment: When you're doing `for i in list1` you're basically looping through the elements of the list and each `i` is `"1"` or `"2"`. Now you can't index the list with this `i`, you need to use `for i in range(len(list1))` for that. Also you shouldn't modify the list while looping through it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str - iterating list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23326716/typeerror-list-indices-must-be-integers-not-str-iterating-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`list1` is a list of strings. This is because the numbers have quotes - `" "` around them.

In your for loop, you are looping over these strings, each iteration of the loop `i` is set to a string, "1", then "2"...

When you call `pop(i)` you are passing a string to it, but you need to pass an integer.

It can be helpful to print what is going on your program, for example in your loop you can

```
print(i, type(i))
```

to help keep track of what is going on.

Not sure what your end goal is with this, but there are nice clean ways to keep track of what you are lopping over.

```
for i, element in enumerate(list):
```

will give you access to both the current element, and the current iteration at the same time.

Using this in your example could look like:

```py
list1 = ["1", "2", "4", "5", "3"]
for i, element in enumerate(list):
    if element == "3":
        list.pop(i)
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be misunderstanding how the `for-loop` is looping through your list.

Based from your code its iterating through your list rather than creating an index to be used to access an element on your list. You should be using `range()` if you want to us an index:

```
list1=["1","2","4","5","3"]

for i in range(len(list1)):
    if list1[i]== "3":
        list1.pop(i)
        break
print(list1)
```

Comment: better use `list1.remove("3")` that does exactly the same thing.

Comment: what if there are multiple "3"?

Answer (score 0):

In your original for loop, you're iterating through each element of the list, which are all strings. The error you're receiving says you can't slice a list by strings, and instead you need to slice by an integer. I would recommend slicing by indices.

To do this, you only need to change the beginning line of your for loop:

```py
for i in range(len(list1)):
```

Now it should work as expected, because it's looping through the index of your list (i.e. 0,1,2,3,4).

Answer (score 0):

When you do something like

```
for i in list1
```

`i` gets the values of elements in the list, so i becomes "1", "2", etc... These are strings, and you can't index lists with strings. You'd better do something like

```
for elem in list1:
    if elem in ['3']: ...
```

Of course, if you just want to remove an element from a list, you can use:

```
if elem in list1:
    list1.remove(elem)
```

Comment: and protect `remove` just in case the element isn't in list

Comment: I would have used an exception, which is more performant, since with your method, the list is searched 2 times. And advise not to use `list` as a variable name (pedantic, I know...)

Comment: I used the OP's variable names. As for performance - do we have a performance issue here we need to solve?

Comment: OP is using `list1` not `list`.

Comment: Apparently so am I!

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

```
list1 = ["1","2","4","5","3"]

for index,value in enumerate(list1):
    if value in ["3"] : # this condiation can be (value in ["3","2"])
        list1.pop(index)
        break
print(list1)
```

The result is `['1', '2', '4', '5']`.