# Python TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not float Error

Tags: python, for-loop, typeerror, user-defined-functions, inner-product

I am getting a TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not float on the fourth line of code when I run this. nums and nums2 are simply asking the user to provide a list of numbers that will be used to calculate the inner product in the code that I have provided.

```
def innerproduct(nums, nums2):
    for i in nums:
        if i in nums2:
            sum +- nums[i] * nums2[i]
    return innerproduct
```

I'm not sure why this error is occurring and how to resolve this issue, so any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str - iterating list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23326716/typeerror-list-indices-must-be-integers-not-str-iterating-list)

Answer (score 0):

`for i in nums` means that `i` will store the value in nums list, not the index.

for example if nums = [1.5, 6.2, 0.1] then i would be `1.5` and `nums[i]` is throwing that error.

either you can do `for i in range(len(nums)):` and get `nums[i]` or just `for i in nums` and then sum += `i` instead of `nums[i]`

Answer (score 0):

Extending Shubham's answer,

update your code with the below snippet and your code will work

```py
def innerproduct(nums, nums2):
    sm = 0
    for i,num in enumerate(nums): # enumerate returns index of item & actual item
        if num in nums2:
            sm += num * nums2[i]
    return sm
```