# How to solve TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not sockets

Tags: python, list, typeerror

I want to create a TCP server which can send specific messages to specific clients. In my example, I have two clients Iconet and Robot. I want to send specific messages to each of these clients once they are connected.

I am able to establish a connection from the client, but when the code enters the `handle_client` function I am running into troubles. I am not sure where my mistake lies. When I run the code, I am given a TypeError which says

> list indices must be integers or slices, not sockets

**Server code**

```
import threading 
import socket 

PORT = 9000
SERVER = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
ADDR = (SERVER,PORT)
FORMAT = "utf-8"
HEADER = 1024
DISCONNECT_MESSAGE = "END_CYCLE"

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind(ADDR)
clients = []
aliases = []
alias_dictionary_iter = zip(aliases,clients)
alias_dictionary = dict(alias_dictionary_iter)

def handle_client(conn,addr):
    print(f"[NEW CONNECTION] {addr} connected.")
    while True:
        for client in clients:
         if client == clients[0]:
            robot_message = 'VITA_R'
            clients[client].send(robot_message.encode(FORMAT))
            robot_response = aliases[client].recv((HEADER).decode(FORMAT))
            print (robot_response)
         elif client == clients[0]:
            iconet_message = 'VITA_I'
            clients[client].send(iconet_message.encode(FORMAT))
            iconet_response = aliases[client].recv((HEADER).decode(FORMAT))
            print (iconet_response)
            
def start():
    server.listen()
    print(f"[LISTENING] Server is listening on {SERVER}")
    while True:
        conn, addr = server.accept()
        print(f"[NEW CONNECTION] {addr} connected.")
        conn.send('NAME?'.encode(FORMAT))
        alias = conn.recv(1024)
        aliases.append(alias)
        clients.append(conn)
        print(f'The clients is {alias}'.encode(FORMAT))
        thread = threading.Thread(target= handle_client, args=(conn, addr))
        thread.start()


print ('[STARTING] server is starting')
start()
```

**Client code**

```
import threading
import socket
name = input('NAME? ')
client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect(('10.14.0.2', 9000))


def client_receive():
    while True:
        try:
            message = client.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
            if message == "NAME?":
                client.send(name.encode('utf-8'))
            else:
                print(message)
        except:
            print('Error!')
            client.close()
            break


def client_send():
    while True:
        message = f'{name}: {input("")}'
        client.send(message.encode('utf-8'))


receive_thread = threading.Thread(target=client_receive)
receive_thread.start()

send_thread = threading.Thread(target=client_send)
send_thread.start()
```

Here is the complete error message

```
PS C:\Users\shoni\Documents> python -u "c:\Users\shoni\Documents\TcpCommExample\Server and clients\server8.py"
[STARTING] server is starting
[LISTENING] Server is listening on 10.14.0.2
[NEW CONNECTION] ('10.14.0.2', 56533) connected.
b"The clients is b'Rob'"
[NEW CONNECTION] ('10.14.0.2', 56533) connected.
Exception in thread Thread-1 (handle_client):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\shoni\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 1009, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\shoni\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 946, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\shoni\Documents\TcpCommExample\Server and clients\server8.py", line 26, in handle_client
    clients[client].send(robot_message.encode(FORMAT))
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not socket
```

Comment: can you share the complete error stack trace ?

Comment: Hey, i have edited the question to include the error message in its entirety

Comment: What is `clients[client]` supposed to do?

Comment: My aim is to send a message to the specific `client` but i am not sure if `clients[client]` is the correct way to achieve it

Comment: No it's not, `for client in clients` extracts an actual content of the list, not its index. You seemed to apply that correctly with `if client == clients[0]:`.

Comment: so can i just simply apply `client.send` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str - iterating list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23326716/typeerror-list-indices-must-be-integers-not-str-iterating-list)

Answer (score -1):

`clients` is a list, so you can do

```
clients[1]
```

or

```
clients[:1]
```

and since `client` is an object (type socket), that cannot be used for `clients` list.

```
clients[client]  # WRONG
```

Comment: So how do I use the list to send message to `client` if i cannot use `clients[client]` ?

Comment: why not just `client`?

Comment: @navyad `clients[:1]` still gives a list.

Comment: @matszwecja thank you, it works when i use `client`.

Comment: @matszwecja but the part
 ```elif client == clients[1]:
            iconet_message = 'VITA_I'
            clients[client].send(iconet_message.encode(FORMAT))
            iconet_response = aliases[client].recv((HEADER).decode(FORMAT))
            print (iconet_response)``` 
is still not being performed when a second client is being connected

Comment: @Sho Why do you expect `client == clients[0]` being False in `if` part, but True for `elif` part?

Comment: @matszwecja sorry i meant to say `client == clients[1]`